# How to fix Column not found error when adding data to the database [SQLSTATE[42S22]]

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

Am trying to add data to the database using this line

```
$this->project->description()->create( $this->getDescriptionData() );
```

How do i deal with this error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'description' in 'field list'`? Note that the field description already exists in the database table am tring to insert the data to.

#### ---------------

I have a `Project` class that `hasOne( ProjectDescription::class)`, and the ProjectDescpription class `belongsTo(Project:class)`.

In the ProjectDescription class i have a `description` field set to `$fillable`.

### what I tried

I have tried renaming the description field in the database to content and doing the same in my code. Yes it works but I need to understand why it does  not work when the column is set as `description`

#### migration for the project description table

```php
       Schema::create('project_descriptions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('project_id');
            $table->text('decsription');
            $table->integer('payment_method_id');
            $table->bigInteger('target');
            $table->string('image_path')->nullable();
            $table->string('video_url')->nullable();
            $table->dateTime('start_date')->nullable();
            $table->dateTime('end_date')->nullable();
            
            $table->longText('options')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

#### Here is my Project class and project description class respectively

```php
class Project extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'user_id', 'category_id'];

    /**
     * description
     *
     * @return Modules\System\Entities\ProjectDescription
     */
    public function description()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(ProjectDescription::class);
    }
```

---

projectDescription

```php
class projectDescription extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [ 'description', 'payment_method_id', 'target', 'image_path', 'video_url', 'start_date', 'end_date'];

    /**
     * project
     *
     * @return Modules\System\Entities\Project
     */
    public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
    }
```

I expect that the data will be written into the db but instead i get this sql error while the column in question already exists in my database table

```sql
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'description' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `project_descriptions` (`description`, `payment_method_id`, `target`, `image_path`, `video_url`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `project_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (dgtfjkgfbgnyt ghvb mkyu, 1, 1200, , https://www.youtube.com/watch2019-04-25v=1J0-BzpFjMg, 2019-05-17, 7, 2019-04-20 23:42:24, 2019-04-20 23:42:24, ?))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **migration for the project description table**

Change

```
$table->text('decsription');
```

to

```
$table->text('description');
```